# Apache ignore htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a website that uses mod_rewrite for pretty urls. I have two main urls:

```
example.com/id
example.com/generate/id
```

And this htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^generate/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ generate.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)$ contact.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

The first url is working correctly, but the second not. Apache shows a 404 error, I think that it's because it's looking for the folder "generate", that doesn't exist, and it can't find the htaccess in the document root.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any other `Options` directives in .htaccess? In any case -- change `Options +FollowSymLinks` to `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` and ensure that there is no `Options +MultiViews` or similar AFTER that line. Now try problematic URL again. If still nothing -- see if you can enable rewrite debugging (place `RewriteLogLevel 9` into server config / virtual host context) and check rewrite log for exact details.

Comment: Thank you, the error was in the MultiViews option, disabling it the error dissapears

Answer (score 0):

Have you try

```
RewriteRule ^generate\/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ generate.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```